# Similar alternative to Dropbox for hosting HTML pages

Tags: web-development, web-server, google-drive, dropbox

Free Dropbox accounts created before October 2012 had a [public folder](https://www.dropbox.com/help/16) that until, October 2016 could host HTML like so:

`https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/[uid]/[path]/[file].html`.

Support for Pro users ends on September 2017 as well.

I further understand that neither [Google Drive](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html?visit_id=1-636123031464545572-1550336261&hl=en&rd=1), [Onedrive](http://websitesustainability.blogspot.no/2013/07/can-skydrive-be-used-as-free-hosting.html) or [Box.com](https://community.box.com/t5/SMB-Forum/Hosting-a-html-static-website-using-Box/m-p/14100) currently support this scenario .

Are there other desktop-to-cloud syncing tools that support basic HTML hosting?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Mailfence](https://mailfence.com).

However, Mailfence will mirror the files to a virtual drive on your computer and your browser accesses them from that virtual drive.  That may not be precisely what you want.

As a bonus, the virtual drive is password protected and encrypted.